# Multi-valued attributes in a relational database

Tags: database-design, schema, relational-database, erd

What is the best method of implementing multi-valued attributes in a relational database?

I'm trying to convert an ER diagram into a relational schema, and I have this problem:

I have a table of 'Programmes' with attributes such as Programme ID, type, title, description etc - but then also have Actors - obviously this is multi-valued as a specific programme will have multiple actors in.

How should I represent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an actor can have `Many` programmes and a programme can have `Many` actors this sounds like a classic `Many-to-Many` relationship. Create a third table called `programme_actors` or perhaps `cast` with two columns: the primary keys of each of the two joined tables.

Answer (score 1):

If an actor also may appear in several programmes,  use a join table with foreign keys on both programme and actor and possibly other attributes like role.